# What API does iStat Menu use? (Mac power system sensors)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, power, power-management

I am writing a script to procedurally measure certain power system parameters.

I am aware of `system_profiler SPPowerDataType`. However, this API only updates once a minute and sometimes provides quite different results than iStat.

iStat has a number of different sensors for current draw (amperes), all of which update once per second. It also has a power bus (PBus) voltage which updates once per second.

Comment: Have you contacted the iStat Menu developers and asked them?

Comment: A license for iStat menu is at https://bjango.com/help/istatmenus4/licenseagreement/.  They don't want to share their source code.  They may feel like discussing what API they use, but my bet would be against that.

Comment: I contacted them a few days ago, still waiting on a response.

Comment: Did you ever hear back from the developers?